# 'Lock' part of formula when copying from one cell to another

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
=IF(I11="VSS";G11;IF(I11="MCS";0;G11*Totais!C30))
```

I would like to freeze **`Totais!C30`** when I click on bottom right of cell and drag down.

Currently when I do this, `Totais!C30` change to `Totais!C31`, `Totais!C32`,...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

By adding a `$` in front of the column & row you can lock that specific area up when copying.

Example: `Totais!$C$30` would lock down when copying anywhere else in the document. `Totais!$C30` would lock down moving column to column. `Totais!C$30` would lock down when moving down rows.

Comment: What if I have hundreads of such formulas to copy? I don't want to add $ to each one separately.

Comment: This does not lock the formula of a cell so that it cannot be edited. It locks the reference to an absolute reference which can then be copied unchanged to another cell.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to make a big dent in locking down my individual cell formulas.
I went to the formula tab, then I clicked on Show Formulas. I highlighted the first cell of one column, highlighted multiple cells, then I pressed <kbd>F4</kbd>. The dollar sign was added to ALL of the first cell locations in each of the formulas of the cells highlighted. It did not however add it to 2nd or third cell locations within the formulas.
this would probably need to be done one at a time.

Example:

**original**

`=SUM(I3-14)`

`=I6`

`=SUM(I3-E10)`

`=I5`

**AFTER <kbd>F4</kbd>**

`=SUM($I$3-I4)`

`=$I$6`

`=SUM($I$3-E10)`

`=$I$5`

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: This could be useful, but it does not exactly answer the question asked here.