# Google Docs speadsheet auto-fill: control what increments

Tags: google-sheets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Lock' part of formula when copying from one cell to another](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27851/lock-part-of-formula-when-copying-from-one-cell-to-another)

Is there a way to control which variables in a formula get incremented when you use auto-fill in a Google Docs spreadsheet?

What I'm trying to do is convert a column of counts to a column of proportions. So, for the first cell in the proportions columns, I wrote "=E2/sum(E2:E17)". When I drag down the box in the lower right corner to auto-fill the other cells in the column with the appropriate formulas, I get the unintended effect that "sum(E2:E17)" does not stay constant -- in the next cell it is "sum(E3:E18)" and so on. What I'm looking for is a way to make auto-fill leave that part of the formula unchanged.

Comment: i need the same. i know this works fine for MS Excel. couldn't figure a way to do that on Google Spreadsheet though.

Answer (score 38):

You should use the magic `$` sign ;)

If you want that the column stays sticky, do something like `sum($E2:$E17)`

If you want that the row stays sticky, do something like `sum(E$2:E$17)`

If you want that both row and column stay sticky, do something like `sum($E$2:$E$17)`

Comment: This is one of the most useful answers I've seen on a stack exchange site.

Comment: unbelievable! Google Sheets (& Excel) is so powerful when using it right 

Answer (score 1):

You can define an alias for a range in Google Spreadsheets » Data » Mange Ranges.

Then use that alias in a formula instead of `XX:YY` and then auto-fill won't mess it up.