# Keep a variable while copy/paste cell

Tags: google-sheets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Lock' part of formula when copying from one cell to another](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27851/lock-part-of-formula-when-copying-from-one-cell-to-another)

I am using in one of my spreadsheets a formula referencing the column title (matching how many times it is listed in another sheet, to be precise). Something like, in *Cell B2:*

```
=IF(countIf(Data!2:2;B1)>0 ;"present","absent")
```

So if, in the row2 of the sheet `Data`, the first line/title (B1) of my column(B) is present at least one time, it writes `present`, otherwise it writes `absent`.
This is working without problems.

**The problem happens when I try to use this formula for the next row**, if I paste it in B3, it looks like (*Cell B3):*

```
=IF(countIf(Data!3:3;B2)>0 ;"present","absent")
```

The `B1` from my original formula becomes `B2` and now refers to the value of the previous row.

**How can I keep a variable static whenever I copy/paste the cell ?**

(I do still want for the other values to increment)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like in Microsoft Excel, you can use the `$` to make an [absolute reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-formulas-HP010081865.aspx#BMusing_references_in_formulas).

Thus, you could try this:

```
=IF(countIf(Data!2:2;$B$1)>0 ;"present","absent")
```

Here is a Stackoverflow thread about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984282/excel-formula-meaning-of

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick answer, exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

Just like in Excel, you need to put a dollar sign `$` before the column and row header in your formula like this:

`=IF(countIf(Data!2:2;$B$1)>0 ;"present","absent")`

If you want the column and row of B1 not to change. I don't know which of both you want static, you can take away one of the $'s.