# How to drag down 'A1:A2', 'A1:A3', 'A1:A4'

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say every day (1 day = 1 row) a number is being added in column A
I want to have column B show the total of these numbers. However, if I drag it down, it keeps moving 'B1' too, while I only want the second one to move +1 -->. So:

```
Cell B1: '=A1' 
Cell B2: '=SUM(A1:A2)'
Cell B3: '=SUM(A1:A3)'
Cell B4: '=SUM(A1:A4)'
```

etcetera.
Dragging this down doesn't give the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do this by increasing the formula by a cell for each row. This is not possible.

Instead, you use as the formula

```
cell B1 = A1
cell B2 = SUM(B1, A2)
cell B3 = SUM(B2, A3)
```

Now you can drag down the formula from B2 and B3 (don't include B1 in the selection!) for as many rows as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in that case ...

Use the following formula in B2:

```
=SUM(A$1:A2)
```

The `$` sign is meant to fix the row. If you it drag horizontally, I will follow the column letters.

See answer given, here on Web Applications: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/27869/29140

Answer (score 1):

Since OP wants a result even in B1 I suggest a small variation on @Jacob Jan Tuinstra's A, in **B1** and copied down to suit:

```
=sum(A$1:A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness ...

Insert in cell B1:

> =SUM(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,ROW(A1)))

Then, just copy or drag it down.

Note that the answer by rumtscho is much more efficient, though.

Answer (score -1):

Use the dollar sign before the thing you don't want to change:

B2 = SUM(A2:A$1)

Now, when you drag this down, it becomes, say:

B10 = SUM(B10:A$1).

The "1" in A1 remains as it is because it was prefixed by the dollar sign.

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: That does not work, `B10=SUM(A10:A$1)` but `B10<>SUM(B10:A$1)` also seems to me once corrected a duplicate of [@Jacob Jan Tuinstra's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/55062/) posted 2 years earlier (albeit with the range flipped).